# Choppy scrolling with absolute positioned elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have many absolute-positioned elements inside an absolute-positioned parent element. I want to have direct control over the scrolling using the `onWheel` event in React. The problem is, when I have too many elements, the scrolling becomes choppy. If, rather than controlling the scrolling manually with `onWheel`, I leave it to the browser, the scrolling is as smooth as butter.

Here is a code sandbox so you can see what I mean. Scroll anywhere in the righthand window to see the choppiness. If you go to the bottom of the code, and change the line `ReactDOM.render(<ManualScroll />, rootElement);` to `ReactDOM.render(<DefaultScroll />, rootElement);` the choppiness disappears. If you're on Mac, you may need to disable the "swipe between pages" trackpad setting in system settings.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nnnz3nr27l

How can I achieve this level of smoothness while retaining direct control over the scrolling?

Here's what I've tried:

- Using `translate3d` rather than translate, both on the `graph` class and the `node` class
- Debouncing the onWheel event
- Using `window.requestAnimationFrame` to update the positions, rather than doing it directly in the `onWheel` handler

Comment: Maybe you're debouncing too long or perhaps waiting until the next frame is waiting too long?

Comment: Actually, I think it's just that you're manipulating (and rerendering) 5,000 elements on every scroll. You should definitely be using something like the canvas api for this

Comment: My guess would be 5000 elements as well. Changing the value to 500 will make it smooth. Another way of doing this is to just move the 100 elemnts that are to the left  and 100 elements that are to the right of the screen. While keeping another 4800 stationary until they are needed. Then swspping the outermost element with the stationary.

Comment: Yeah, doing some trickery to only move the elements that are on-screen or close to being on-screen was my next idea. Is this how browsers achieve the desired level of smoothness? I.e., when I set `overflow: auto` on the parent element?

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 I'd love to use canvas, but these elements will actually contain a bunch of regular html - text, images, etc. There won't really be 5,000 individual elements, but there could be 5,000 elements when all the children's children are accounted for. The simple shapes are just to illustrate the issue.